# How to pass multiple arguments through ssh and use those arguments in the ssh script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, scripting, shell-scripting

I have written one script on lets say `server1` and from that script I want to execute script `Start_UI_AdminApp.sh` on `server2` through ssh. I also need to pass the arguments while executing this ssh command. So that i have to use those arguments in `sc.sh`. This is my script which I am trying to execute

I am calling my server1 script as below

```
./server1.sh 3005 BuildNO_7
```

Below is my script from `server1` (`server1.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
port=$1
directory=$2
ssh user@server2 "bash -s" < /home/server/scripts/Start_UI_AdminApp.sh "$port $directory"
echo "Script executed"
```

This is the error which I am getting when executing the command `./server1.sh 3005 BuildNO_7`

```
./server1.sh: line 4: /home/server/scripts/Start_UI_AdminApp.sh: No such file or directory
Script executed
```

Comment: is `/home/server/scripts/Start_UI_AdminApp.sh` on server1 or server2 ? what you want is rather like `bash /home/server/scripts/Start_UI_AdminApp.sh $port $directory`  (or without bash if you set execution bit.

Comment: /home/server/scripts/Start_UI_AdminApp.sh is on server 2.

Comment: then what you want is `ssh user@server2 bash /home/server/scripts/Start_UI_AdminApp.sh $port $directory`

Comment: Thank Archemar it worked.